# Memory allocation algorithm over a growing storage

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, memory-allocation, storage

I am going to story data in a growable persistent storage. I need to implement allocation/deallocation (like malloc/free and possibly realloc but in Rust) of continuous regions of memory on this storage.

Allocation should never fail, but the storage grow if out of allocated storage.

Priorities:

- Should do alloc/dealloc quick (i.e. desirably logarithm time of data size). That is the most important priority.
- Prefer not to grow the persistent storage if possible (because the persistent storage price is proportional to its size).

Please describe a data structure holding allocated and free regions of memory an algorithm matching the requirements.

I am writing this in Rust. If this helps, I write/read persistent storage by one word, so reading/writing are relatively slow operations.

As a bonus, if not too hard to implement, I would like also abillity of splitting long regions of allocated storage into blocks (as in fragmented filesystems).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Manual_memory_management

Comment: "as in fragmented filesystems" There's a clue right there. It sounds an awful lot like what you want to implement is kind of like a filesystem. Of course, filesystems don't necessarily store contiguous files in contiguous disk blocks. Is that a requirement?

Comment: @Pseudonym For simplicity it could be implemented without fragmentation. But adding fragmentation may be useful.

Comment: @D.W. Wikipedia misses a description of the data structure used to track allocated memory. I need a description of such a data structure.

Comment: I've found https://github.com/microsoft/mimalloc - it remains to translate it to Rust and use input/output instructions instead of direct memory access.

Comment: Another alternative to base Rust code on: https://jemalloc.net/

Comment: Or https://github.com/microsoft/snmalloc

Comment: Or there is a Rust code (so easy to port), but said not being very performant: https://lib.rs/crates/dlmalloc

Answer (score 0):

There is [this Rust allocator](https://github.com/zakarumych/blink-alloc) described as "blazingly fast".

It remains to rewrite it with I/O functions instead of direct memory access.

Comment: That's a pool allocator. It would be very easy to implement that on disk, however it doesn't support deallocating individual objects. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_pool

Comment: @Pseudonym I've also noticed this. Therefore, should I delete my answer?